# Best practice for grouping ingredients and measures from a JSON API

Tags: javascript, json, backend

I am using a JSON API for drink recipes and the ingredient and measure information is structured in separate key-value pairs with incrementing numbers, like strIngredient1, strIngredient2, and strMeasure1, strMeasure2, etc. I want to loop over the ingredient and measure pairs together and avoid accessing null variables, but I am not sure what the best approach is for grouping them.

I have tried the following code to extract the data and group the results, but I am open to better solutions:

```
let numberOfIngredient = 1;
let numberOfMeasure = 1;
let ingredientArr = [];
let measureArr = [];

Object.keys(drinkData).forEach((key) => {
  if (key === `strIngredient${numberOfIngredient}` && drinkData[key] !== null) {
    numberOfIngredient++;
    ingredientArr.push(drinkData[key]);
  }
  if (key === `strMeasure${numberOfMeasure}` && drinkData[key] !== null) {
    numberOfMeasure++;
    measureArr.push(drinkData[key]);
  }
});

for (let i = 0; i < ingredientArr.length; i++) {
  console.log(ingredientArr[i], measureArr[i]);
}
```

What is the most effective way to group the strIngredient and strMeasure pairs together to create an array of ingredient-measure pairs for each drink recipe?

Comment: Why don't you just give your desired outcome?

Comment: I update now. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a connected Element of Ingredient name and Measure so a List of Ingredient Elements ({ingredient, measure}).

You for example could go for a simple loop.

```
let ingredients = {
   "strIngredient1": "Watermelon",
        "strIngredient2": "Mint",
        "strIngredient3": "Grapefruit Juice",
        "strIngredient4": "Lime",
        "strIngredient5": "Tequila",
        "strIngredient6": "Watermelon",
        "strIngredient7": "Mint",
        "strIngredient8": null,
        "strIngredient9": null,
        "strIngredient10": null,
        "strMeasure1": "1/2 cup",
        "strMeasure2": "5",
        "strMeasure3": "1/3 Cup",
        "strMeasure4": "Juice of 1/2",
        "strMeasure5": "1 shot",
        "strMeasure6": "Garnish with",
        "strMeasure7": "Garnish with",
        "strMeasure8": null,
        "strMeasure9": null,
        "strMeasure10": null
};
let groupedIngredients = {};
for (let ingredientKey in ingredients) {
  let ingredientID = ingredientKey.split('strIngredient')[1];
  if (ingredientID) {
      if (!groupedIngredients['ingredient_' + ingredientID] && ingredients['strIngredient' + ingredientID] !== null && ingredients['strMeasure' + ingredientID]) {
        groupedIngredients['ingredient_' + ingredientID] = {
            ingredient: ingredients['strIngredient' + ingredientID],
            measure: ingredients['strMeasure' + ingredientID]
        };
      };
  }
}
```

The Result will look like this:

```
{
    "ingredient_1": {
        "ingredient": "Watermelon",
        "measure": "1/2 cup"
    },
    "ingredient_2": {
        "ingredient": "Mint",
        "measure": "5"
    },
    "ingredient_3": {
        "ingredient": "Grapefruit Juice",
        "measure": "1/3 Cup"
    },
    "ingredient_4": {
        "ingredient": "Lime",
        "measure": "Juice of 1/2"
    },
    "ingredient_5": {
        "ingredient": "Tequila",
        "measure": "1 shot"
    },
    "ingredient_6": {
        "ingredient": "Watermelon",
        "measure": "Garnish with"
    },
    "ingredient_7": {
        "ingredient": "Mint",
        "measure": "Garnish with"
    }
}
```

Comment: nice!! I update my solution. please give a note.

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like this would be short and functional:

```
Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { 
 const [,prefix,id] = key.match(/(.*?)(\d+)/i);
 acc[prefix] = [...(acc[prefix] || []), value];
 return acc;
}, {})
```

See here for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/xcksfj32/1

Additionally: if you want to filter null values you can do this:

```
Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { 
 const [,prefix,id] = key.match(/(.*?)(\d+)/i);
 if (value) {
   acc[prefix] = [...(acc[prefix] || []), value];
 }
 return acc;
}, {})
```

Comment: Can you explain ```acc[prefix] = [...(acc[prefix] || []), value];``` this?
I update my solution. please give a note.

Comment: `acc` is the result object. `prefix` is the key after splitting with the regex so this will retain `strIngredient`. I'm updating `output[strIngredient]` with the destructuring of the result (or an empty array if it is `undefined` => `...(acc[prefix] || [])`) and adding the `value`. Hopefully this makes sense.